# CSS Hover Removal on Tap

Tags: css

I have a CSS menu that when you hover over a `li` it shows a sub menu, example ui: http://www.screencast.com/t/JIa2NvbreF8V

I added code that on a model device is would 'focus' the element when you click/tap it, like: `$($event.target).focus();`

problem is, when I tap a `<a href="\blah">` link inside my page navigates fine but my menu stays open.  I tried retriggering the body to be the focus but no luck.  Anyone got a good idea on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is add a class to control the "focused" state, so that when you click on a link you can easily remove it.

Shouldn't be complicated but i would need to look at the code :O

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
   $("a").focusout(function(){
   $(this).css("display","none");
  });
```

Regards
maha

Answer (score 0):

inside that jquery selector have it so when you click the target it also changes the style for the parent li:hover

Comment: how do you remove a hover?